# How do I make a path to my css file from my html file?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a path to my CSS file from my html file. I had my folder opened with my E: drive usb and all of my files are save there as I edit the code. I'm having trouble to write a path to my css file from my html files. What I have is a main folder which consist of another 2 folder and they are labeled CSS and HTML. For each folder, I have style.css on CSS folder and the other file is index.html file inside the HTML folder.

If anyone can solve this issue, please share with me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following folder structure:

```
E:
  main
    HTML
      index.html
    CSS
      style.css
```

You can include your CSS file, relative to the HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
```

The `../` means you go one folder up from the current (HTML, where your index.html is), then you are in the main folder, so just use `CSS/style.css`.

Comment: thank you so much! it works.

Comment: Happy to help! If an answer solved the issue please accept it by clicking on the checkmark.